# Trim first character if it equals to 3 in apex outputtext

Tags: visualforce

I was wondering if there's an inline code to solve this.

I'm placing an apex outputtext on a visualforce page but I want to remove the first character if that first character equals to three.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Visualforce Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm).  Under the Text Functions, there are `BEGINS`, `RIGHT`, and `LEN`.  Try:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(BEGINS(myText, '3'), RIGHT(myText, LEN(myText) - 1), myText)}"/>
```

Comment: haha, beat ya by 7 seconds....But you took the extra time to link to the casual reading document......And for shame, you used RIGHT, no love for MID??? lol

Comment: it was the RIGHT thing to do ;)

Comment: Touche!!!!......

Comment: @dotmiko - This is the right answer so when you accept please select this one as it includes the required reading material for this course.....

Answer (score 1):

Sure....

Here is an example using the Account Name

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">


    <apex:outPuttext value="{!IF(BEGINS(Account.Name,'A'),MID(Account.Name,2,LEN(Account.Name)-1),Account.Name)}"/>

    </apex:page>
```